# socket sendto not working on Android (kivy, buildozer)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I am writing a script in kivymd to toggle an LED which is connected to a microcontroller. The script is supposed to send a socket UDP msg to the MCU server, which includes a command to toggle the LED. The script works fine on windows, and the building with buildozer is successful (although not shown in this script but I tried another version to simply print hello world to an MDLabel and it worked) but whenever I press the btn_led on Android, the application shuts down. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
import socket


class TableApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
     
        # Add Widgets
        screen = Screen()

        btn_led = MDFlatButton(text="Toggle LED", on_release=self.toggle_led,
                           pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5})

        screen.add_widget(btn_led)
        return screen

    def toggle_led(self, event):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.sendto(b"LED", ("10.0.0.167", 1111))
        s.close()


TableApp().run()
```

Comment: Do you handle permissions?

Comment: The only permission I could see on my phone is a storage permission. Do you have a type of permission in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned that the buildozer.spec file contains permissions which can be configured to include `INTERNET`. I uncommented the permissions line which contains INTERNET by default and everything worked like a charm!